# Gnupg gives "get_key failed" despite using a valid key

Tags: php, gnupg, pgp

I want to integrate PGP encryption into my web application, after looking for what to use(extensions, libraries, etc.) I decided to go with the gnupg extension for php. Now, I do have a PGP key in one of my desktop folders and I've tried to use it's fingerprint as a string for `addencryptkey`, the error I receive is `get_key failed` which I don't understand why, my PGP key is valid.

There are two very similar questions on SO:

[php gnupg get_key failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705359/php-gnupg-get-key-failed-error) ,

[gnupg get_key failed in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937118/gnupg-get-key-failed-in-php) ,

Based on these, I've updated my code somewhat to no success, here's what it currently looks like:

```
  putenv("GNUPGHOME=/home/user/Desktop/Keys/.gnupg/");

  $pgp = new gnupg();

  $pgp->addencryptkey("F0E2DF9C82ECE67935171F4939D8599A923820D9");
  echo $pgp->geterror();
```

In the folder specified in `putenv`, I have my public key saved in a `.asc` file. I can't see what the problem really is, unless it only works with keys stored on the server?

Comment: I just ran into this problem and I solved it by calling import with the contents of the public key I was using rather than pointing it to an existing public key folder.

Answer (score 0):

I *just* wanted to share my fix for this issue. Given that this is one of the more recent questions on this topic I thought it best to share it here.

At the time I was able to encrypt messages fine (PHP 7.4 with the GNUPG PECL extension).

To address the `get_key_failed` error, after setting up/importing my keys I copied my entire `.gnupg` directory to the root of my webserver (/var/www/html in my case) and updated its permissions so that it was accessible by the webserver.

```
putenv("GNUPGHOME=/var/www/html/.gnupg");
```

I assumed that this would fix it, however I then encountered a new error when attemping to decrypt a message:

```
Uncaught Exception: decrypt failed
```

The only way I could resolve this was by ensuring my key pair **did not** have a passphrase. Some comments on the PHP GNUPG docs suggest that that passphrase which is the second argument on `adddecryptkey()` is ignored regardless. However, in my case decryption only worked with a private key that didn't have a passphrase set.

This worked on my local instance (Ubuntu 18) and when deployed to an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2.